# Core Data, Fetch request

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I wrote this method to read my database, but every time I call it, it creates a new core data object with nil NSManaged Objects. Why is this happening?

---

```
func readDatabaseWithStringArrayAndStrings() -> (String, [MyContactCard]?)
{
    let context = self.appDelegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = MyContactCard.createFetchRequest()
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do{
        var str="" //str obj

        let myResults = try context.fetch(request)


        print("myResults results: \(myResults)")

        return (str, myResults)

    }
    catch{
        return (error.localizedDescription, nil)

    }
}
      //caller 
  _ = MyContactCard(context: self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext).
      readDatabaseWithStringArrayAndStrings()
```

---

**Output**

[image: first method execution]
*first method execution*

[image: second method execution]
*second method execution*

Comment: The fetch is fetching what is there.  Somewhere else in your code you are inserting a new object without assigning values to the properties.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't understand how? There is no parameter passed in. Everything reference object is created inside of the function?

Comment: The code you have shown only reads data.  Where is your code that inserts a new `MyContactCard` entity?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have updated the code with the caller. Does this mean every time I call this function, I am creating a new object?

Comment: Yes.  The `MyContactCard(context: self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)` is creating a new `MyContactCard`.  Have you created the `readDatabaseWithStringArrayAndStrings` function in your `MyContactCard` file?  If so, then you probably want that function to be a class function or to exist in some other class

Comment: Ok; I understand how new objects are being created every time MyContactCard() gets called. Yes, it is inside the MyContactCard file. Why is it a problem for the readDatabaseWithStringArrayAndStrings to be in the MyContactCard Class?

Comment: You can do it, if you make it a class function, but you have to be careful; if the MyContactCard file is automatically generated code then your changes will be lost if you change your object model.